# 1.17.1 Minecraft Jar Folder

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to find the (version).jar folder for 1.17.1 but it is not there, all that is there is a .json file.
Does anyone know where it is?

Answer (score 1):

If there's only the JSON file, it means the .jar hasn't been downloaded yet. You must launch 1.17.1 from the launcher at least once - at that point the launcher will download the .jar from Mojang's servers before starting the game.